# zero patterns of M-matrices and their invereses

Tags: matrices, matrix-theory, nonnegative-matrices

Suppose that the matrix $M$ has non-positive off-diagonal elements. The matrix $M$ is
said to be an M-matrix if $M$ is non-singular and each entry of $C:=M^{−1}$
is non-negative.

I think I've proved the following implication: If $M$ is *symmetric*, then

$$ c_{ij}=0 \Longrightarrow m_{ij}=0 \quad (\textrm{for all } i\neq j)$$

Is this implication well-known? I did a quick literature search, but I could not find this precise statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't encountered this exact result, but a closely related one is a complete characterization of the possible zero patterns for inverse M-matrices in https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2009.03.022.

It seems to me that this one can be proved with the same techniques (decomposition into irreducible blocks + keeping track of nonzeros in the Neumann series). I like this result and the short formulation that you found, but probably it is not deep enough to warrant a publication alone.

Incidentally, it seems that the possible zero patterns for $C$ admit a simple description in the symmetric case: any M-matrix $M$ can be written (by permuting rows and columns conformably) as a block upper triangular matrix whose diagonal blocks are irreducible M-matrices; in the case in which $M$ is symmetric, this means a block diagonal matrix. The inverses of irreducible M-matrices are strictly positive, hence $M^{-1}$ is a block diagonal matrix with the same block sizes and only nonzeros in its diagonal blocks. So, in conclusion, $M^{-1}$ is a block diagonal matrix in which the diagonal blocks have all strictly positive entries.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. So, if I understand it correctly, then the last part of it implies the implication from my question more or less directly?

Comment: Yes, in the end, because $M$ is block diagonal and $M^{-1}$ is block diagonal with blocks full of nonzero. It is just a sketch of the proof though.

Comment: Is there a similar simple proof in the non-symmetric case?

Comment: @GiulianoBasso I don't know of a simpler one than the one in the paper I linked.